# Where can I buy bear banger launcher and ammunition and have them shipped to US?

Tags: united-states, bear-bangers

I need bear bangers and launchers, but I live in the US. I've found a site that sells [Launchers and Bear Bangers](https://kodiakcanada.com/collections/launchers-and-bangers) but they only ship to Canada, it seems.

Where or how can I obtain bear bangers and lauchers in the US?

Comment: What? explosives available in Canada but not in USA? Unheard of, absurd... ♪ *No bear bangers in USA, unthinkable.* ♬

Comment: http://meta.outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/838/where-can-i-buy-vs-price-shopping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Previous FFL note was wrong.

According to [Sutton](http://www.suttonag.com/epcd_license_help.html), a special license is required to possess these. They require a Explosive Pest Control Device (EPCD) License which must be obtained from the [Federal ATF](https://www.atf.gov/explosives/apply-license).

Once you have a license [Sutton](http://www.suttonag.com/shell_crackers.html) will sell to US customers.  Read carefully when looking online.  Some vendors, such as [Margo](https://www.margosupplies.com/usa/bangers), only sell the government agencies (fine print, bottom of page).

Comment: What does FFL mean?

Comment: Federal Firearms License -- I am far from an expert but it is required for the shipping of some arms.

Comment: Probably better to say the shipping of nearly all firearms in the US. There are some exceptions, but they're largely for shipping long arms ( rifles) to yourself or to a manufacturer for repair.